# Getting a sized user image [Podio API]

Tags: api, podio

I have a problem, I am developing a smartphone orientated page, so I want the content the less heavy possible. 
In my solution I am using the `PodioContact` class to get the user thumbnail link of the image. 
But the users image are to heavy for my solution, is there a way to get a smaller sized image ?

Code I am using:

```
$contact = PodioContact::get_for_user($id); 
$image=$contact->image->thumbnail_link:
```

Answer (score 4):

Podio saves user profile avatar images in the following sizes:

- `tiny`: 16x16
- `small`: 32x32
- `medium`: 80x80
- `large`: 160x160

If you append `/` and one of those names to the end of the `thumbnail_link` value, you should get the image with the appropriate dimensions.

For example, based on the URL I got back for my own thumbnail, I can construct the following sized image URLs:

- 16x16: `https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/263819120/tiny`
- 32x32: `https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/263819120/small`
- 80x80: `https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/263819120/medium`
- 160x160: `https://d2cmuesa4snpwn.cloudfront.net/public/263819120/large`